# Check your review stats

Tags: support, review, statistics

Where can you find your review stats, such as review audits, average number of time spent on each review task, etc?

Comment: At least the number of reviews and list of all reviews - but separately per each review type - can be found if you go to the [review history](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) for some of the queues and click on *my review history*. The direct link to your close votes review history would look like: `http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/history?userId=YourId` (Similarly for other review queues.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I remember seeing a post where someone posted something to do with average time spent on each review...

Comment: You can also have a look at posts [tagged review-stats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review-stats) on the main meta to see whether some posts there are related to what you want to find.

Comment: If you mean [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15044/what-should-one-do-if-they-see-extremely-fast-reviewing), in that specific case the average time was calculated manually for a group of reviews which were done immediately after each other. There are also some related posts on the main meta, such as [How can one see how much time was spent on a review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276688) and [Can anybody see how long a user spent on a review task?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279793).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Apparently only mods/very high-rep users can see them

Comment: @MartinSleziak No, I saw it somewhere when I was looking up what would happen after failing several review audits (not that I did, of course:p)

Comment: Moderators do have such statistics, normal users do not.